# Error "Cant Find EOCD position" while loading project from Monticello

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, monticello

I Have set up an Monticello HTTP repository in my Windows pc. After i published my project in pharo 2.0 on to the repository from my Mac. Later i tried to load the project on another 2.0 image in windows and i found this error. Cant Find EOCD position. But i am able to load the project in another image in mac.

Anybody have some idea what must be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .mcz file that was created by my Pharo image was malformed. After retrying the whole procedure , i managed to publish to the HTTP repository and then was able to load from both windows and mac.